# check the list of numbers different more than one in prolog

Tags: list, prolog, clpfd

I have a list of numbers in prolog. the numbers are already sorted.I want to check any of the numbers are not repeated and different between any two numbers is greater than one.How to check it. any idea. Thank you.
 
`?- check([1,3,4]).     %expectation`
`false.`
`?- check([2,5,7,10]).    %expectation`
`true.`

Comment: What have you tried? Since you're dealing with sorted numbers, you only need to check consecutive values. Use the fact that a list can be written as, `[X1, X2|T]` where `X1` and `X2` are the first two elements in the list, and `T` is the rest of the list (the tail, also a list).

Comment: Your wording is very imperative. Think about describing **what holds**. Ideally, the resulting relation will then be usable in *all directions*, and will be much more general than a "check": You will also be able to *generate* solutions with it. See [tag:clpfd] for describing relations about integers.

Comment: If I understand you correctly... you do not want to check that "different between **any** two numbers is greater than one". but instead "difference between **all** adjacent numbers is greater than one." Right?

Comment: yes.any of the "difference between all adjacent numbers is greater than one." is the correct form how i will get it?

Comment: Hint: add @<username> to notify a specific user in a comment... I came back by pure coindicence...

Comment: Which Prolog processor (B, Ciao, GNU, SICStus, SWI, XSB, YAP) are you using?

Comment: Are the numbers you care for all integers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume list alreadeTry it...
`check([_]).`
`check(L):-append([],[X1,X2|T],L),X1+1<X2,check([X2|T]).`

Comment: Why use `append/3` in this context? Simply write `check([X1,X2|T]) :- ... .` instead of `check(L) :- append([],[X1,X2|T],L), ... .`

Comment: Yes it is correct my list is already sorted.also add`check([]).` for the empty list.

Answer (score 2):

Let me guess...

- you are using SWI-Prolog, and
- all numbers that your `check/1` cares for are integers.

If so, read on!

---

Use [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd)!

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
```

As you already might have guessed, there are a billions and billions of ways to implement the predicate `check/1`. In this answer we use a straight-forward, directly recursive approach:

```
check([]).
check([_]).
check([E0,E1|Es]) :-
   E0+1 #< E1,
   check([E1|Es]).
```

Sample queries:

```
?- check([1,3,4]).
false.

?- check([2,5,7,10]).
true ;                   % do not be bothered by the trailing `; false`
false.                   % `true ; false` is equivalent to `true`
```

Have you noticed the binary operator `(#<)/2` in above definition of `check/1`?

It allows us to run general queries and get logically sound answers. Consider!

```
?- Xs = [1,A,B,C], check(Xs).
Xs = [1,A,B,C], A in 3..sup, A#=<B+ -2, B in 5..sup, B#=<C+ -2, C in 7..sup ;
false.
```